# A wordpress plugin upload guideline

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to upload my wordpress plugin on wordpress.org.

Now the structure of my plugin is

```
redirect (this is the plugin foldername)
redirect.php (it is the main file with all the logic)
read.txt (this is read me file )
```

My question is that do I need to add more directories or any other files in this folder to be accepted on wordpress.org.

Can anybody guide how to go farward from here and upload my plugin successfully on wordpress.org but I am concerned if I need to add any new files into my main plugin folder.

Answer (score 0):

All informations which you need, you will find here https://wordpress.org/plugins/add/ (check left sidebar links)

Your read.txt file should be renamed to readme.txt and has this structure: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt